# Pig Parse XML with nexted multi-occurrence tags using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-pig

Need help to read nested/multi occurrence xml tags using XPath and XPathAll
Example:

```
<ProductInfo>
 <code>100</code>
 <entryInfo> 
    <statusCode>10</statusCode>
    <startTime>11</startTime>
    <endTime>12</endTime>
 </entryInfo> 
 <entryInfo>
    <statusCode>20</statusCode>
    <startTime>21</startTime>
    <endTime>22</endTime>
    <strengthValue>23</strengthValue>
    <strengthUnits>24</strengthUnits>
 </entryInfo>
 <entryInfo>
    <statusCode>30</statusCode>        
    <endTime>32</endTime>
    <strengthValue>33</strengthValue>
    <strengthUnits>34</strengthUnits>
    <extra>35</extra>
 </entryInfo>  
</ProductInfo>
```

Expected output:
100,10,11,12,,,,20,21,22,23,24,,30,,32,33,34,35

While reading first occurrence of entryInfo and child tags XPath is going to second occurrence for $0 to find missing tag

```
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/statusCode’).$0,
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/startTime’).$0,
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/endTime’).$0,
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/strengthValue’).$0,
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/strengthUnits’).$0,
XPathAll(x,’ProductInfo/entryInfo/extra’).$0
```

Output;
10,11,12,23,24,36